# 7 segment 4 digit not showing numbers 2,3 and 0

Tags: arduino-nano, wires, 7-segment

https://www.instructables.com/Using-a-4-digit-7-segment-display-with-arduino/

I used this link to make my circuit and I used this code also but some numbers like 2,3 and 0 doesn't display correctly.[image: (This is the error. First number is 1 second is 2 third is 3 and fourth is 0)]

Comment: So your answer given here is not quite accurate? https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/77524/4-digit-7-segment-display-not-showing-value-properly/80525#80525

Answer (score 6):

It looks like you have the center segment and the top left vertical segment reversed. For the image you show, if you switched the on/off states of those 2 segments, you'd see `1230`.

I don't know if the problem is in your code or in your wiring. The simplest fix would be to swap the pins for those 2 segments.

Comment: Thanks it works.

Comment: You should accept my answer if it solved your problem. That is a strong norm on this site. Up-voting helpful answers is optional (once you have enough reputation for that) but also considered good form.